# Kernel panic - java Tainted error due to UseLargePages

Tags: jvm, kernel, centos6, jvm-arguments

I'm running into a weird issue of "Kernel Panic" while trying to use **UseLargePages** as one of the JVM parameters. The moment I try to execute any java command, the OS hangs and I'm forced to re-bbot.I'm using 64 bit CentOS 6.2 (Linux 2.6.32-220.23.1). Here's what I did to set-up the LargePages.

- Added the following entries in **/etc/sysctl.conf**

```
kernel.shmmax = 4294967296
vm.nr_hugepages = 2048
vm.hugetlb_shm_group = 502
```

- My jvm is running under root user, so added root as part of this group --> **hugetlb**
- Updated **/etc/security/limits.conf** to add the following

```
root            soft    memlock         4194304
root            hard    memlock         4194304
```

- Updated kernel command line to use non-transparent hugepages **transparent_hugepage=never**
  meminfo shows

  ```
  cat /proc/meminfo | grep Huge
  AnonHugePages:         0 kB
  HugePages_Total:    2048
  HugePages_Free:     2048
  HugePages_Rsvd:        0
  HugePages_Surp:        0
  Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
  ```

  Finally, I added the "-XX:+UseLargePages" as one of the JVM startup parameters.Now, the moment I run any java command, e.g. "java -version", the OS hangs, I had to resort to a re-boot. Here's a stacktrace from the OS log.

**Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception
Pid: 1790, comm: java Tainted: G      D    ----------------   2.6.32-220.23.1.el6.centos.plus.x86_64 #1**

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception

Pid: 1790, comm: java Tainted: G      D    ----------------   2.6.32-220.23.1.el6.centos.plus.x86_64 #1

Call Trace:
 [] ? panic+0x78/0x143
 [] ? xen_restore_fl_direct_end+0x0/0x1
 [] ? _spin_unlock_irqrestore+0x1c/0x20
 [] ? oops_end+0xe4/0x100
 [] ? no_context+0xfb/0x260
 [] ? __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x111/0x940
 [] ? __bad_area_nosemaphore+0x125/0x1e0
 [] ? __raw_callee_save_xen_pmd_val+0x11/0x1e
 [] ? bad_area_nosemaphore+0x13/0x20
 [] ? __do_page_fault+0x31d/0x480
 [] ? __lru_cache_add+0x40/0x90
 [] ? xen_set_pte_at+0xaf/0x170
 [] ? page_add_new_anon_rmap+0x9d/0xf0
 [] ? handle_pte_fault+0x487/0xb50
 [] ? do_page_fault+0x3e/0xa0
 [] ? page_fault+0x25/0x30
 [] ? __unmap_hugepage_range+0x1f2/0x300
 [] ? __unmap_hugepage_range+0xdf/0x300
 [] ? unmap_hugepage_range+0x54/0x90
 [] ? unmap_vmas+0xae7/0xc00
 [] ? release_pages+0x21c/0x250
 [] ? check_events+0x12/0x20
 [] ? xen_force_evtchn_callback+0xd/0x10
 [] ? check_events+0x12/0x20
 [] ? unmap_region+0x91/0x130
 [] ? do_munmap+0x2b6/0x3a0
 [] ? sys_munmap+0x56/0x80
 [] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
Xen Minimal OS!
```

Not sure what's causing this issue. I'm not an OS expert,so don't have a lot of clue to interpret the log. Everything works if I turn of UseLargePages option by commenting **kernel.shmmax = 4294967296**. The totaly memory of the machine is 15gb. I'm using -**Xmx6144M -XX:MaxPermSize=128m** as JVM memory parameters. Is it something to do with CentOS 6.2 ?

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: Shamik, Have you found any solution on this ? If yes then please guide me because I am also facing same problem currently.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani .. Unfortunately, I couldn't make it work in CentOS 6.2. It worked for me though in CentOS 7.